# TCP port testing not accurate with `ip = ipaddress.ip_address(args.ip)`

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, sockets, argparse

In this test machine, `tcp/80` is listening while `tcp/4444` is not. (I already verified this with `netstat -an`)

If I simply pass `args.ip` value to `ip`, and forward it to `scan()` function, the scan result is always accurate.

```
ip = args.ip
```

**Normal Output:**

```
C:\>python script.py 127.0.0.1
Port number: 80
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80
OK 127.0.0.1:80

C:\>python script.py 127.0.0.1
Port number: 4444
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:4444
FAIL 127.0.0.1:4444

C:\>
```

However, when I try to validate IP Address with the following function

```
ip = ipaddress.ip_address(args.ip)
```

the scan result is always wrong.

**Wrong Output ... tcp/80 is up and running:**

```
C:\>python script.py 127.0.0.1
Port number: 80
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80
FAIL 127.0.0.1:80
```

What's wrong with this code?

```
import socket, argparse, ipaddress

def main():
    global ip
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-u')
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    group.add_argument('-i')
    group.add_argument('ip', nargs='?')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.i:                                      
        print("IP Address is .. " + args.i)
    elif args.ip:                                   
        ip = ipaddress.ip_address(args.ip)          # Prob
        #ip = args.ip                               # OK
        scan()
    elif args.u:
        print("URL is " + args.u)
    else:
        print('No argument provided')

def scan():
    port = input('Port number: ')
    print('Connecting to %s:%s' % (ip,port))    
    try:
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((ip, int(port)))
        print('OK %s:%s' % (ip, port))
    except:
        print('FAIL %s:%s' % (ip, port))

main()
```

Would it be possible to validate the IP Address and then forward it to another function and still getting the correct port scanning test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to pass an `IPv4Address` instead of a string to `s.connect`.

It would be more apparent if you didn't use a catch-all `except`. This is what you get without it:

```
thierry@amd:~$ python3 test.py 127.0.0.1
Port number: 80
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 16, in main
    scan()
  File "test.py", line 27, in scan
    s.connect((ip, int(port)))
TypeError: str, bytes or bytearray expected, not IPv4Address
```

Just use `str(ip)` instead of `ip`:

```
def scan():
    port = input('Port number: ')
    print('Connecting to %s:%s' % (ip,port))    
    try:
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((str(ip), int(port)))  # ip is an IPv4Address
        print('OK %s:%s' % (ip, port))   # no problem here, str will be used for print
    except ValueError:
        print('FAIL %s:%s' % (ip, port))
```

---

```
thierry@amd:~$ python3 test.py 127.0.0.1
Port number: 80
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80
OK 127.0.0.1:80
```

You might also want to change your `except:` into `except ConnectionRefusedError:` to avoid to catch all exceptions indistinctly.

Comment: Wow!!! Many thanks. I spent hours looking at this code but couldn't figure it out. Could you please share any tips how did you debug this kind of problem quickly?
Btw, I'm still new with Python ... just started it.